# Finding unused classes in C# app

Tags: c#

I'm a C#/.net/Visual Studio noob. I inherited a half-completed C# application for a mobile phone. In the course of debugging, I came across several half-finished classes that don't seem to be used anywhere else in the code. Is there a way to get determine if a class definition is instantiated anywhere?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The quickest way (in Visual Studio) is to right-click the type name and select *Find all references* from the context menu.  This will show you all places where that type is referenced in the current solution.

Comment: Pressing SHIFT-F12 is arguably quicker. :)

Comment: If a class A is referenced only from some class B which is not used, the class A can be considered not used, too.

Answer (score 3):

You should get [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) - it will show "dead" code in grey and make refactoring a lot easier! You may also prefer [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/).

Answer (score 2):

Without ReSharper or a similar tool, you can always do a file search for "new ClassName(" in the entire solution.

Comment: Or types instantiated via Reflection.

Comment: @Erik: the other solutions won't work for types instantiated via reflection as well.

Comment: @Vlad - that is true. I don't really have a solution to offer, given that there really isn't one that covers all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

I usually start with Shift-F12 (or right-click on class name and select "Find All References")

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know the code, and the modules that may use it., CodeRush or Resharper are your better choices.

None of the other answers mentioned the modifiers which can be applied to classes/functions.  You certainly want to take scope into consideration before deleting code.  You may have other assemblies which use classes/functions.

Answer (score 0):

Remove them from the project and let your unit tests (ahem, you have those right?) and your QA team (you have that right?) identify the problems.

Jokes aside, if it's SO obvious that it's not complete, why not simply remove the code and recompile?

The next steps I would take would be to use a tool like "Find All References" or Resharper (does it even have a feature to do that?)

Comment: This code was inherited from a college student intern. It does not have unit tests. I will add unit tests, but before I can do that I need to understand the code, which is rather difficult when there are classes and methods that are not even used.

While reviewing the code before check-in I spent a significant amount of time trying to figure out how a seemingly broken method works. I'm not a C# guy, so I spent time looking through docs thinking something magic was happening, when in fact it was indeed broken, and just not called from anywhere :(

Answer (score -1):

You can list all the classes (searching for `class [a-zA-Z0-9_]+`), and then search for `new <classname>`. The ones not found at the second search are not used. Of course, a simple script in your favourite script language would help.

You'll need however to filter out the classes that are used as base classes of used classes.

Note that this way you'll not find the classes which are used only from unused classes, so several iterations might be needed. Moreover, if some two classes are using each other (but not used from outside), removing them might need additional effort.

Edit:
A better approach would be building dependency tree: for each of the classes you define which class is used by that class, and which class is a base class for that class. This way you find which classes are required for every single class. Then, you can define which classes are required (directly or indirectly) from the class containing `Main`. All other classes are "unreachable" and therefore not used.

This approach will however remove the classes instantiated by reflection. Well, there is no way to find out at compile time, which classes are going to be instantiated by reflection anyway.

Maybe using the ready tools (like others proposed) is a simpler alternative.